# iOS How to manage different features that requires a 3rd-party framework

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-frameworks

I developed an SDK distributed to our publishers as a standard iOS framework.
To be as much clear as possibile let's say my SDK is called 'A'.
'A' needs a 3rd-party iOS framework (called 'B') that manages a particular feature.
So, for example, I have a class in 'A' like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <B/SomeClassOfB.h>

@interface MyClassOfA : NSObject < 'B' Delegate>
```

Import of 3rd-party framework and my class is conform to a protocol of 'B'

Now, if I have a publisher in the USA that want use this particular feature, I will send to him my framework plus 3rd-party framework, publisher links both of them to his app and everything works. Yeah!!

Now the problem.... if I have a publisher in Europe that don't want use this particular feature, I don't want to send him 3rd-party framework and he doesn't want to add something completely useless to his app.
Which is the best way to achieve this problem? How can I build two different frameworks, one with the above class that depends to 'B' and one that ignore it without "comment" code every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another `target`.

[image]

If you just want to distinguish .h or .m files, then create these files with the same filename(or class name) but different filepath, then edit "Target Membership"

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I obtain: "Duplicate interface definition for class". I put files in different folder and changed target membership.

Comment: @GiulioBider Can you post an example project?

Comment: yes, I will post it tomorrow. By the way, if I have 2 .m files and 1 .h everything works. I need to have 2 .m and 2.h because headers and implementation are different. But if I create 2 .h files, I get the above error.

Comment: It's OK to have the same fileName or className in a project, no matter .h or .m, just use "target membership" to tell Xcode compiler to link the correct files.

Comment: Thank you Elf. After some hours on it, everything is working great! :)